# Sum of two state functions is not path independent

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, differentiation, mathematics

I am trying to explain the different physical meanings of the various thermodynamic potentials (before resorting to Legendre transforms, and without making appeals to statistical mechanics) and I wanted to motivate this by introducing two simple state functions $\alpha = TS$ and $\beta = -PV$. I was then trying to show that linear combinations of these with the first law create all of the other thermodynamic potentials ($A$/Helmholtz, $H$/enthalpy, $G$/Gibbs). I figured that state functions should form a structure that is closed under addition and subtraction, but they don't, i.e.
\begin{gather}
d(U - PV) = T dS - 2 P dV - V dP
\end{gather}
and hence $\frac{\partial^2 (U-PV)}{\partial V \partial P} \neq \frac{\partial^2 (U-PV)}{\partial P \partial V}$. Why is this? All state functions must be path independent and therefore have exact differentials, correct?

Why would the sum or difference of two state functions not be a state function?

Comment: $U$ is a function of $S$ and $V$, not of $p$, so your derivatives do not make much sense.

Comment: $U$ can be a function of any two thermodynamic variables so long as one is intrinsic and one is extrinsic

Comment: I don't know if I can follow. The problem seems to be, at a first glance, that you treat $p$, at the one hand, as an independent variable (like $S$ or $V$), and on the other hand as a derivative of $-U$... You see: If $p=-\partial_V U$ then $p$ is a function of $V$ and $S$ itself. However, when you write $\partial_{pV}^2(U-PV)$, then you treat $p$ as independent.

Comment: Just think of $U-PV$ as a different state function. Even if you don't, the derivative $\frac{\partial^2 (U-PV)}{\partial V \partial P}$ still makes sense just view $U$ as a function of $V$ and $P$ and obviously $PV$ is a function of $P$ and $V$. You can differentiate an independent variable with respect to itself: $\frac{d }{dx} (x) = 1$

Comment: Aha. Can you define the function $U(S,V,P)$ for me, please?

Comment: I really don't understand what you do here, but I might miss something due to the usual hardcore abuse of notation in thermodynamics. The function $(S,V)\mapsto U(S,V)-P(S,V)V$ is indeed a state function.

Comment: let me to add to what @TobiasFunke is saying. You wrote $\frac {\partial^2}{\partial p \partial V}$ implying that you have $T=T(p,V)$ and $S=S(p,V)$, now expand and then the two derivatives are actually the *same* when you realize that the transformation Jacobian of $S, V \to p, V$ is actually 1. One may say that this is actually a *proof* that the Jacobian is indeed $1$. Do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would venture to offer a simple formal explanation of why the arguments leading to the paradoxical inequality of mixed partial derivatives of the state function are incorrect. There were adequate comments here, but I don't see in them exactly what I want to say. The thermodynamic quantities $S$, $P$ and $V$ are not independent; one of them can be expressed as a function of the other two. For example, $S = S(P,V)$. For this reason, the differentials $dS$, $dP$ and $dV$ are linearly dependent. Therefore, the following equalities are false
$$
\frac{\partial(U-PV)}{\partial V} = -2P,\quad \frac{\partial(U-PV)}{\partial P} = -V.
$$
In fact, there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, functions of $P$ and $V$, such that
$$
dS = \alpha dP + \beta dV
$$
According to this equality and the basic equality of the question, the correct expression for partial derivatives would be
$$
\frac{\partial(U-PV)}{\partial V} = -2P + T\beta,\quad \frac{\partial(U-PV)}{\partial P} = -V + T\alpha
$$
Of course, $T$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are functions of $P$ and $V$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial^2(U-PV)}{\partial V\partial P} = \frac{\partial^2(U-PV)}{\partial P \partial V}.
$$